# Create self signed iis ssl certificate from powershell

Tags: iis, powershell, ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate

I need to create a new self-signed IIS SSL certificate from a PowerShell script as part of an automated install.

**Here's what I've tried:**

```
Import-Module WebAdministation

New-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -IP "*" -Port 443 -Protocol https

New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject Fluency -DnsName $computerName.$domainName -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My

Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My | where { $_.Subject -match "CN\=$Computername\.$DomainName" } | select -First 1 | New-Item IIS:\SslBindings\0.0.0.0!443
```

**Result**

It says New-SelfSignedCertificate cannot be found for that line. If I create the certificate manually through the IIS manager, the rest of the code works fine.

*Thanks for your help!*

Comment: From [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463297/using-powershell-to-create-self-signed-certificate?rq=1) is [a link to a TechNet article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16226.quick-start-guide-for-integrating-a-single-forest-on-premises-active-directory-with-windows-azure-ad.aspx) that may help you out.

Answer (score 21):

I got it to work this way

```
    Import-Module WebAdministration

    Set-Location IIS:\SslBindings

    New-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -IP "*" -Port 443 -Protocol https

    $c = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "myexample.com" -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My

    $c | New-Item 0.0.0.0!443
```

Comment: For anyone coming across this solution you need to import the WebAdministration module first, so `Import-Module WebAdministration` followed by `Set-Location IIS:\SslBindings`